# Facebook Registration and Login Apps, Need Guidance

Tags: facebook, registration

I have used Face book Apps for register and login for my website (in PHP). Problem is very simple for you all experts. 
When I try to login via FaceBook using my email id which I am using for Facebook developer login then I succeed but if I give any other email ID I can't able to login.
Ex.
x123@yahoo.com is id which I'm using for Facebook Developer Account
a123@gmail.com is normal Facebook user account.
Now if use x123@yahoo.com for login in my website, I am successful and redirected to Profile Page)
But if I use a123@gmail.com for login in my website I FAIL and I come back on same page from where I tried to login
Any guidance will help me to move forward I'm stuck here

Comment: Are you running the app in Sandbox Mode?

Answer (score 0):

By the reading of your problem I think you have your app on Sandbox mode. If you want to test on other profiles, you should consider creating [Test Users](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/test_users/).

Depending of your purposes, you may create another app just to make your tests (and therefore need not to be on sandbox mode).